# Finding folders in a directory (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, subdirectory

I am using the code below to search for all text files in a directory.

```
import os

numOfFiles=0
files=[]

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        files.append(file)
        print(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
        numOfFiles=numOfFiles+1
```

How would i find all sub-directories within the variable `dir_path` using my existing code?

Comment: I think you need `os.walk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `isdir()`:

```
import os

numOfFiles=0
files=[]

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        files.append(file)
        print(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
        numOfFiles=numOfFiles+1
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        # ...Do something
```